# VB.NET TextBoxFor Lambda Expression

Tags: lambda, textbox, vb.net-2010

I am learning about MVC2 but the book looks at C# syntax only. However, I come from a VB background so I would like to know the VB.NET of the expression below:

```
<p>Your Name : <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x >= x.Name)%> </p>
```

When I use the code above, the compiler complains that 'x' is not yet declared.

If you have an answer or can provide a link to another question which has the solution, that would be great.

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p>Your Name : <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Name)%> </p>
```

Comment: OK that worked. Thanks Andrew! Is there some online resource that details this syntax or do I need to go buy an MVC2 VB.NET book? Cheers

Comment: The MSDN reference on VB.Net Lambda Epxressions is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx